# A sequence $\{x_n\}$ if of bounded variation. Prove $\exists a_n, b_n$ such that $x_n = a_n - b_n$ where $a_n, b_n$ are bounded and increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Prove that for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ of bounded variation there exist increasing 
>    bounded sequences $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ such that $x_n = a_n - b_n$ for $n\in \Bbb N$

This problem appears in the context of [theese](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166134/prove-a-sequence-with-bounded-variation-converges) [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163556/prove-that-convergence-of-a-sequence-implies-boundedness-of-its-variation) problems. Those two posts show some properties related to the bounded variation of the sequences. Now I want to show the last part, namely what's in the problem statement.

I was thinking of the following sketch. Let's suppose $x_n$ may be presented as a difference of the two sequences, namely:
$$
x_n = a_n - b_n
$$
Then what is left to show is that both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are increasing. Since the variation is bounded then it must follow:
$$
\exists \lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma_n = L\\
\exists \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = x
$$

Then:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sigma_n - \sigma_{n-1}) = 0 \\
\begin{align}
\sigma_n - \sigma_{n-1} &=
|x_{n+1} - x_n| \\ 
&= |(a_{n+1} - b_{n+1}) - (a_n - b_n)| \\
&= |(a_{n+1} - a_n) - (b_{n+1} - b_n)|
\end{align}
$$

It follows that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} |(a_{n+1} - a_n) - (b_{n+1} - b_n)| = 0 \implies \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_{n+1} - a_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(b_{n+1} - b_n) = C \tag1
$$

But this seems to be a road to nowhere. What would be the way to show $a_n$ and $b_n$ are increasing and bounded? Because according to $(1)$ it looks like $a_n$ and $b_n$ are not even bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define $a_n=x_1^{+}+(x_2-x_1)^{+}+\cdots+(x_n-x_{n-1})^{+}$ and $b_n=x_1^{-}+(x_2-x_1)^{-}+\cdots+(x_n-x_{n-1})^{-}$ where $x^{+}=\max\{x,0\}$ and $x^{-}=-\min \{x,0\}$.